# SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges working on Windows Server 2003/SP2007 and not on 2008/SP2010

Tags: development, delegate, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have this simple code in C# using SharePoint:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost:333");
});
```

When I execute it on a Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2010 I get this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {BDEADF26-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80040154.

When I execute it on Windows Server 2003 with SharePoint 2007 it works well.

Is there a problem in Windows or Sharepoint?
How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Is SharePoint installed AND working on your 2008 server?

Comment: Do you have an alternate access mapping for "http://localhost:3333"?  SharePoint pays attention to host headers and generally frowns upon "localhost" and IP addresses.  Have you tried "http://<server_name>:3333"?

Comment: @Kirl There is an error on SPSecurity the execution doesn't get to opening the SPSite

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was your code compiled for 64-bit?

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: The answer in my case was no. And that was the problem, because it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Try registering OWSSVR.DLL file located under ISAPI folder under 12-hive (MOSS 2007) or SharePoint root (Sharepoint 2010) folder. It is a COM library, you need to register using "REGSVR32 'FULL PATH TO DLL' command.

Comment: I tried registering like this: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\OWSSVR.DLL but there is an error : C:\Program failed to load. How can i solve the space issue?

Comment: specify the path in quote...

Comment: I got this error: The module was loaded but the call to DLLRegisterServer failed with error code 0X80040201

Comment: open the command prompt using "Run as Admin" and try again.. D

Comment: Also, change target cpu of your project to "Any Cpu" or "x64"

Answer (score 1):

Goto your Visual Studio Solution Properties --> Set the Platform target as AnyCPU for Build option. It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following step and it worked for me for the above error.

- Go to Solution Explorer and press Alt+ enter
- Select Any CPU in Build option and uncheck the box that says, Prefer 32-Bit.
- Save the changes and Build your solution.

Now You should be able to Run the program.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For SP2010, Take reference of Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll from 14 hive.You have to rebuild the project for 64 bit